# how to assign a value to a radio button Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

Hi I'm trying to make a currency converter for USD and EUR

I declared the radio buttons as
radioUSD
radioEUR

and I want to assign a value to the radio buttons
radioUSD = 0.395
radioEUR = 0.447

I'm new to cocoa

I tried so Many solution online but didn't work

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBOutlet weak var radioUSD: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var radioEUR: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Label: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var value: NSTextField!

var us = 0.395
var eur = 0.447

@IBAction func calc(_ sender: Any) {
    Label.doubleValue = value.doubleValue * us
}

override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}
```

}

I expect the output to be if I choose 
usd the value * 0.395
and for our the value * 0.447

[the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMSCb.png)

Comment: As it is right now, seems like you're always going to be multiplying by `us` according to your code: `Label.doubleValue = value.doubleValue * us`. Is this what you're experiencing? Also, what do you expect the inputs/outputs to be? If you have the USD radio button on, does that mean you're input is USD and you would output EUR or that you're typing in EUR and expect USD out?

Comment: A radio button doesn't have a value, it has a state: on or off. Use `us` if `radioUSD` is on and use `eur` if `radioEUR` is on.

Comment: @LucasDerraugh no when I select USD I want the value of text box to be multiply by 0.395 and display it in label so as for EUR when I select it I want to be multiply by 0.447

Comment: @Willeke can you explain a way to do that or give me a tutorial cause I am new to this thanks in advance

Comment: @The-_-King_464 What Willeke is saying. You have variables `us` and `eur` that aren't related to the sender value in `calc` (the radio buttons don't have the values of us or our). You need to do something like `if radioUSD.state == .on { multiply by usd } else if radioEUR.state == .on { multiply by eur }`

Answer (score -1):

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Currency Converter
//
//  Create`enter code here`d by Firas Albusaidy on 6/30/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Firas Albusaidy. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var radioUSD: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var radioEUR: NSButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: NSTextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var value: NSTextField!
    var us = 0.395
    var eur = 0.447
    @IBAction func calc(_ sender: Any) {
        if (radioUSD.state == NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 1))
        {
            Label.doubleValue = value.doubleValue * us
            print ("Radio 1 Selected");
        }
        else
        {
            Label.doubleValue = value.doubleValue * eur
            print ("Radio 2 Selected");
        }
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: You can just use `.on` instead of `NSControl.StateValue(rawValue: 1)`